# Oracle SYS_REFCURSOR couldn't use as a return type

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to extract and display all the years for all the records in db using member function in oracle 11g.

```
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY student_t AS 
MEMBER FUNCTION getYear RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
yearDOB SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    for c in (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) c_year from student s)
    loop
        yearDOB := c.c_year; 
    end loop;
    return yearDOB; 
END;END;/
```

Since I need to return multiple values for the extract function I have declared a SYS_REFCURSOR type variable to return. But it will generate following errors.

```
7/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored,
7/14     PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

output after changed as following answer.

### S.GETYEAR()

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

### C_YEAR

```
  1993
  1995
```

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

### C_YEAR

```
  1993
  1995
```

student type as follows.

```
create type student_t as object(
stno char(4),
dob date)/ 
alter type student_t add member function getYear RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR cascade;/
```

Comment: You get multiple results because you are calling the function as the projection of a query on STUDENT so obviously the function will execute once per record in the table, Two rows = two executions = two result sets. If the table had ten rows you would get ten executions and ten result sets. To run once use the special Oracle table DUAL: `select get_year() from dual;`

Comment: Can you please post the full definition of TYPE `STUDENT_T` and the table.

Comment: Again, please don't insert pictures! Copy/paste the result as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but I think you misunderstood concept of object in oracle. 
In my example i'm assuming
1) Table studens is create with this script `create table student of student_t;`

`drop table student;`

Create  type spec and body.

```
create or replace type student_t as object(
stno char(4),
dob date,
member function getYear return number

)
;

create or replace type body student_t as

    member function getYear return number is 
    begin 
            return  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM self.dob);
    end;

end;
```

Create table of studnets

```
create table student of student_t;
```

Populate tabel

```
declare 
  v_student student_t;
begin 
for i in 0 .. 10 loop 
  insert into student values(student_t('ST'||+mod(i,3),to_date('01-01-'||to_char(2000+i),'dd-mm-yyyy')));
end loop;
commit;
end;
```

And the query.

`select  s.*,s.getYear() from student s;`

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler:

```
yearDOB SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN yearDOB for 
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) c_year 
    from student s;

    return yearDOB; 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks that works but retrieve the same result twice. How should I get only one output?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "retrieve the same result twice". Perhaps you are looking for `SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.dob) c_year FROM ...`

Comment: I have updated the question with the output image. There actually twice is number of records. Maybe that because of the for keyword. But without for can we?

Comment: DISTINCT also give the output for number of records @Wernfried Domscheit. So how we can solve?